# Help in writing equation in indicial form (summation convention)

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

How can I write the following equation in indicial form, following the summation convention?
$$\frac{1}{q}=\frac{cos^2 \alpha}{k_x}+\frac{cos^2 \beta}{k_y}+\frac{cos^2 \gamma}{k_z}$$

$q$ is a scalar value.

$k_i$ is a second rank tensor, $k_{ij}$. This equation assumes the eigenvalues of $k_{ij}$ to be colinear with the coordinate system axes, $x,y,z$, and thus is why the 2nd-rank tensor is denoted with a single subscript in the equation above.

For the numerators on the right-hand side, let's denote the unit vector $v_i$ as $(\cos(\alpha), \cos(\beta), \cos(\gamma))$, where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the angles that $v_i$ makes with the $x,y,z$ axes respectively.

Would writing this equation in indicial notation be as simple as?:
$$\frac{1}{q}=\frac{v_i^2}{k_{i}}=v_i^2 k_i^{-1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your assumption, the symmetric $(0,2)$-tensor $k_{ab}$ is non-degenerate, so that there exists a unique symmetric $(2,0)$-tensor $k^{ab}$ such that $k^{il}k_{lj} = \delta^{i}_j = k_{jl}k^{li}$, i.e., the $(2,0)$-tensor $k^{ab}$ with non-zero components $k^{11} = k_x^{-1}$, $k^{22} = k_y^{-1}$, $k^{33} = k_z^{-1}$; note that this is exactly the same procedure used to go between metrics and inverse metrics in (pseudo-)Riemannian geometry, e.g., in general relativity. Taking $v_a$ to be your unit (co)vector, you can therefore write your equation covariantly as $$\frac{1}{q} = k^{ij}v_i v_j.$$

Comment: (+1) For more of your help...In writing my question, I assumed $k_{11}=k_x, k_{22}=k_y, k_{33}=k_z$. Therefore, for the equation you wrote, I would think that $k_{ij}v_iv_j=q$, and when in the principal coordinate system, $q=k_iv_i^2$, and this relation in terms of direction cosines $q=k_x \cos^2 \alpha+k_y \cos^2 \beta +k_z\cos^2 \gamma$. If we take $r_{ij}$ as the matrix inverse of $k_{ij}$, i.e., $r_{ij}=k_{ij}^{-1}$, then I think your equation, if written as $1/q=r_{ij}v_iv_j$ makes sense. BUT, I'm likely wrong in all of this. Appreciate if you can point out where.

Comment: Ah, your $k^{ij}$ is equal to $k_{ab}^{-1}$?